# Entity Framework Core relationship with alternate paths

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to use Entity Framework Core 8 to read (only) from a database I cannot modify (database first) and that does not include explicit foreign keys. After scaffolding, I therefore need to manually define relationships. I need help defining a relationship between 2 tables that can either be direct through a foreign key, or indirect through a third table if the foreign key is not defined.

Consider the following entities

```csharp
public partial class Procedure
{
    [key]
    public string ProcedureId { get; set; }

    public string ProcedureName { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys
    public string DocumentBaseId { get; set; }
    public string SpecificVersionId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public DocumentBase DocumentBase { get; set; }
    public DocumentVersion SpecificVersion { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentBase
{
    [key]
    public string DocumentBaseId { get; set; }

    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    // Foreign key
    public string DefaultVersionId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public ICollection<DocumentVersion > DocumentVersions { get; set; } = new List<DocumentVersion >();
    public DocumentVersion DefaultVersion { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentVersion
{
    [key]
    public string DocumentVersionId { get; set; }

    public string VersionName { get; set; }

    // Foreign keys
    public string DocumentBaseId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public DocumentBase DocumentBase { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [key]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public ICollection<DocumentVersion > DocumentVersions { get; set; } = new List<DocumentVersion >();
}
```

And the following context

```csharp
            modelBuilder.Entity<Procedure>()
                .HasOne(p => p.DocumentBase)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Procedure>(p => p.DocumentBaseId)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Procedure>()
                .HasOne(p => p.SpecificVersion)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Procedure>(p => p.SpecificVersionId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentBase>()
                .HasOne(db => db.DefaultVersion)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<DocumentBase>(db => db.DefaultVersionId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentVersion>()
                .HasOne(dv => dv.DocumentBase)
                .WithMany(db => db.DocumentVersions)
                .HasForeignKey(dv => dv.DocumentBaseId)
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentVersion>()
                .HasOne(dv => dv.Author)
                .WithMany(a => a.DocumentVersions)
                .HasForeignKey(dv => dv.AuthorId)
                .IsRequired();
```

How can I define a relationship for

```csharp
public partial class Procedure
{
    // Another navigation property
    public DocumentVersion CurrentVersion => SpecificVersion ?? DocumentBase.DefaultVersion;
}
```

Such that queries can use this relationship? For example

```
string author = context.Procedures.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcedureName == "p1").CurrentVersion.Author;
```

The equivalent SQL for the relationship would be

```sql
from Procedure p

join DocumentVersion dv join DocumentBase db on dv.DocumentBaseId == db.DocumentBaseId on ((p.SpecificVersionId = dv.DocumentVersionId) or (p.DocumentBaseId = db.DocumentBaseId and db.DefaultVersionId = dv.DocumentVersionId))
```

I tried simply adding the read-only property but it resulted in a NullReferenceException.

I tried a complex expression for a foreign key

```csharp
            modelBuilder.Entity<Procedure>()
                .HasOne(p => p.DocumentVersion)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Procedure>(p => p.SpecificVersionId ?? p.DocumentBase.DefaultVersionId);
```

but this is not supported.

Comment: Don't you have to use .include?

Comment: Have you scaffolded database? Or it is code-first readonly, which sounds as nonsence.

Comment: Database scaffolding did not create the relationships because the database does not include explicit foreign keys. The relationships have to be added manually.

Comment: Foreign keys are constraints, not relationships. The name is "Foreign Key Constraint" not relationship. In your case you probably didn't have to define any relationship, EF can discover them using naming conventions, eg `Customer.Orders` is a navigation property to `Order` and defines a 1:M relation.

Comment: If you need EF Core only for querying existing database, consider using [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) instead. You can define any navigation property with any complexity via LINQ expression, even it can be extension method with parameters.